# Convergence of a self-consistent multivariable integral equation

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

I want to solve the following integral equation

$$\mathbf v(\mathbf r)=\int_V \mathbf v(\mathbf r^\prime)\cdot \mathbf F(\mathbf r, \mathbf r^\prime) \mathrm ~d^3r^\prime +\mathbf g(\mathbf r)$$

using a self consistency iterative method. Namely,

$$\mathbf v_0=\mathbf g,$$
$$\mathbf v_1=\int_V \mathbf v_0\cdot \mathbf F \mathrm ~d^3r^\prime +\mathbf g,$$
$$\mathbf v_2=\int_V \mathbf v_1\cdot \mathbf F \mathrm ~d^3r^\prime+\mathbf g,$$
$$\vdots$$

Is there a condition that can be applied to determine if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbf v_n(\mathbf r)=\mathbf v(\mathbf r)~\text{?}$$

EDIT: I don't know if it's relevant, but note that $\mathbf F$ is a rank 2 tensor, and $\mathbf v$ and $\mathbf g$ are vectors.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: Thank you, that reference seems very useful.